# finding reminder of (x^n divide p) in O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to finding reminder of (x^n divide p) in O(nlogn), n=2^k;
I write this , but it is not true , can you help me?

```
rem(int x,int n,int p){

if (n==1)
 return x%p;
else
 return rem(x,n/2,p);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on `x`, `n` and `p`? For instance, is `p` a prime? (Also, is this homework?)

Comment: no , p is not prime . it's natural number. I have problem to fin relation for solving this recursively

Comment: Are you sure it is O(n log n)? A naive simple looping can finish it in O(n) already.

Comment: ok, It's not in O(nlogn). this code for some numbers returned true and for some numbers returns wrong answer and it is not in O(nlogn)

Comment: No , I am reading Algorithm  fund. of algorithms book(nipolitan) for my concour exam. but I think this is a wrong question in book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is homework, here is a hint: read on [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), it gives you everything you need to build a solution, including pseudocode.

Your current implementation makes no distinction between even and odd values of `n`, which is correct only when `n` is a power of two. You can expand your solution to work for all `n` (see below).

When you get a return value of `rem(x,n/2,p)` and `n` is even, you should square the result and take a remainder of the square.

You can expand this to work for all `n`, not only powers of `2`, by additionally multiplying the result by `x` and take remainder for odd values of `n`.

Comment: The question and comments imply that n is a positive power of two, in which case the only special value of n is 1.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I missed that part of the question. I updated my answer to talk about odd `n`s as an enhancement to the algorithm.

Comment: is this true: return sqrt(f(x,n/2,p))%p;

Comment: @irisadaf no, `sqrt` takes square root. You need to store the result in a temporary variable, like this: `int temp=rem(x,n/2,p); return (temp*temp)%p;`

Comment: oh oh, I I was confused. But this is not in O(nlog n)

Comment: @irisadaf Right, this is is `O(log n)`. There's no point to add another `n` in there to slow it down.

Comment: I can't understand why it is O(n logn). I think it is in O(log n). because we divide n to 2 each time .

Comment: @irisadaf Of course it's O(log n), I do not know why your book asks for an O(n log n) algorithm. It it very, very likely to be a typo in the book.

Comment: It's Nipolitan book for algorithm. this is very famous book. I don't know it's a typo or this is not answer.Thanks alot

Comment: @irisadaf The publisher's web site does not have a page for errata, but you can always contact the authors and ask. [This page](http://www.neiu.edu/~compsc/cs_faculty.html) has their e-mail addresses, I am sure they will be happy to check if this is an error in the book or not.